# .htaccess rules to rewrite URLs to front end page?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, web-applications, url-rewriting

I am adding a new application to my site at example.com/app. I want views at that URL to always open myapp.php.

E.g.

```
example.com/app -> example.com/app/myapp.php and
example.com/app/ -> example.com/app/myapp.php
```

**What's the correct form of rewrite rules in the .htaccess file?**

I've got:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/
RewriteRule ^myapp\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^myapp.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule . - [L]
</IfModule>
```

...based on what the Wordpress front-end does. But all I see at example.com/app is a directory of files. :(

(I put those rewrites at the top of my .htaccess file).

Any ideas?

**Update**
What actually worked:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /app/myapp.php [L]
```

This is good because:

1. Explicit or implicit calls to app/myapp.php work.
2. example.com/app redirects to app/myapp.php
3. example.com/app/ redirects to app/myapp.php
4. example.com/app/subfunction redirects to app/myapp.php
5. All other calls to example.com/otherstuff are untouched.

Item 4 is Wordpress-like [Front Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) behaviour.

I think that rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app.*$ [NC]
```

needs refining as it allows /app-oh-my-goodness etc. through too.
Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

DirectoryIndex sound more like what you want. (If mod_dir is installed)

```
DirectoryIndex myapp.php
```

Documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html

Or if you still want mod_rewrite, this should work:

```
RewriteRule app(/*)$ http://example.com/app/myapp.php [L]
```

Comment: This is close but spoils needed access to myapp.php (and CSS files etc.) so needs RewriteCond line. See edited question. Also the rule is a little too wide I think. - Great call on "DirectoryIndex". I had forgotten that rule and I like it.

Comment: $ should keep it from matching css or php files. RewriteCond might not be necessary unless it becomes more complex.

Comment: Doesn't "/*" mean "0 or many /", and "/?" is a bit better? Still... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^app/?$ app/myapp.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks - that "?" means "0 or 1 /" - helps a lot. Need rules for app, app/ and app/subfunction really. What about "^app(/.*)?$" ?

Comment: Yes ? means 0 or 1 in this case. That looks correct. And you can use $1 to pass "subfunction" to thr url you are redirecting to.

Comment: You win Best Answer but you are both awesome and helpful!